# g++ broken? Cannot add new methods to class

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors, g++, declaration

I am creating a symbol table class to be used with an analyzer/parser I've written for a compilers course.  Everything has been going well so far, but I cannot get these class files to compile on my school's Linux machines using g++:

SymbolTable.h:

```
// Multiple definition guard
#ifndef SYMBOLTABLE_H
#defineSYMBOLTABLE_H

// Includes
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stddef.h"

// Namespace
using namespace std;

// Class for storing all encountered symbols while parsing
class SymbolTable
{
public:
    SymbolTable();                          // Constructor
    ~SymbolTable();                         // Destructor
    void scopeUp();                         // Increases current scope
    void scopeDown();                       // Decreases current scope
    void addSymbol(string symbolTitle);     // Adds a symbol to table
    void addSymboll(string symbolTitle);    // g++ doesn't think this exists

private:
    int scope;

    // Structure for storing symbols.  Currently only contains title from
    // identifier.  Will expand upon / derive from this structure after
    // initial testing.  Symbols are stored in a simple stack, with the
    // container class responsible for keeping track of the top Symbol.
    struct Symbol
    {
        Symbol* previousSymbol;
        string title;
    };

    // Structure for tracking current scope.  All symbols will belong to a
    // particular scope, and are stored in a simple stack to maintain
    // declaration order.  When the scope changes, currentScope will point to
    // a new scope structure with its own list of symbols.  Scopes themselves
    // are also stored in a stack, where currentScope points to the top.
    struct Scope
    {
        Scope* previousScope;
        Symbol* currentSymbol;
    };
    Scope* currentScope;

    // This is a recursive display function used for printing all of the items
    // in a given scope.  This is called from within the scopeDown function, so
    // that the final list of items for that scope can be logged before it is
    // destroyed
    void displayScope(Symbol* displaySymbol);
};

#endif // Multiple definition guard
```

SymbolTable.cpp:

```
// Multiple definition guard
#ifndef SYMBOLTABLE_CPP
#define SYMBOLTABLE_CPP

// Includes
#include "SymbolTable.h"


// Constructor
SymbolTable::SymbolTable()
{
    scope = 0;
    currentScope = NULL;
    return;
}

// Destructor
SymbolTable::~SymbolTable()
{
    Scope* nextScopeToDelete = NULL;
    Symbol* nextSymbolToDelete = NULL;

    // While there are scopes left to delete from the table...
    while(currentScope != NULL)
    {
        // Save the pointer to the next scope on the stack
        nextScopeToDelete = currentScope->previousScope;

        // While there are symbols left to delete from the scope...
        while(currentScope->currentSymbol != NULL)
        {
            // Save the pointer to the next symbol on the stack
            nextSymbolToDelete = currentScope->currentSymbol->previousSymbol;

            // For debugging
            cout << "deleting symbol " << currentScope->currentSymbol->title << endl;

            // Delete the current top symbol
            delete currentScope->currentSymbol;

            // Move on to the next one
            currentScope->currentSymbol = nextSymbolToDelete;
        }

        // For debugging
        cout << "deleting scope " << scope << endl;

        // Delete the current top scope
        delete currentScope;
        scope--;

        // Move on to the next one
        currentScope = nextScopeToDelete;
    }
    return;
}

// This is a recursive display function used for printing all of the items
// in a given scope.  This is called from within the scopeDown function, so
// that the final list of items for that scope can be logged before it is
// destroyed
void SymbolTable::displayScope(Symbol* displaySymbol)
{
    // If we've reached the bottom of the scope stack...
    if(displaySymbol == NULL)
    {
        return; // Nothing to do
    }

    // We haven't reached the bottom of the scope stack
    else
    {
        displaySymbol = displaySymbol->previousSymbol; // Keep going
        displayScope(displaySymbol); // Recursive call
    }

    // Display this symbol after all lower ones have been displayed recursively
    cout << displaySymbol->title << endl;
    return;
}

// A new procedure has caused us to increase scope, so we'll create a new
// scope structure with its own symbol stack
void SymbolTable::scopeUp()
{
    // Generate the new scope structure
    Scope* newScope = new Scope;
    newScope->previousScope = currentScope;
    newScope->currentSymbol = NULL;

    // Notification for debugging
    cout << "ENTERING SCOPE " << scope + 1 << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------";
    cout << "-------------------------" << endl;

    // Switch to the new scope
    currentScope = newScope;
    scope++;
    return;
}

// The end of a procedure has caused us to decrement scope, so we'll delete
// the contents of the current one and fall back to the last scope on the stack
void SymbolTable::scopeDown()
{
    // If we're already at the bottom of the stack...
    if(currentScope == 0)
    {
        // Something is very wrong
        cerr << "CANNOT DELETE SCOPE 0!!!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the pointer to the next scope on the stack
        Scope* previousScope = currentScope->previousScope;
        Symbol* nextSymbolToDelete = NULL;

        // Display the contents of this scope before deleting it (debugging)
        displayScope(currentScope->currentSymbol);

        // While there are still symbols in this scope to delete...
        while(currentScope->currentSymbol != NULL)
        {
            // Save the pointer to the next symbol on the stack
            nextSymbolToDelete = currentScope->currentSymbol->previousSymbol;

            // Delete the current top symbol on the stack
            delete currentScope->currentSymbol;

            // Move on to the next one
            currentScope->currentSymbol = nextSymbolToDelete;
        }

        // Notification for debugging
        cout << "EXITING SCOPE " << scope-- << endl;
        cout << "==================================================";
        cout << "=========================" << endl;

        // Delete the old top scope from the stack
        delete currentScope;

        // Move on to the next one
        currentScope = previousScope;
    }
    return;
}

// Adds a symbol to the table.  Specifically:  adds a symbol to the top of the
// symbol stack in the scope at the top of the scope stack.  This will soon be
// interfacing with more expansive data structure, but currently just stores
// the title of the symbol as detected in the parser.
void SymbolTable::addSymbol(string symbolTitle)
{
    Symbol* newSymbol = new Symbol;
    newSymbol->previousSymbol = currentScope->currentSymbol;
    newSymbol->title = symbolTitle;
    currentScope->currentSymbol = newSymbol;
    return;
}

// g++ doesn't think this was declared in the class
void SymbolTable::addSymboll(string symbolTitle)
{
    Symbol* newSymbol = new Symbol;
    newSymbol->previousSymbol = currentScope->currentSymbol;
    newSymbol->title = symbolTitle;
    currentScope->currentSymbol = newSymbol;
    return;
}

#endif // Multiple definition guard
```

Errors:

```
[...]$ touch SymbolTable.h SymbolTable.cpp
[...]$ g++ -c SymbolTable.cpp
SymbolTable.cpp:67: error: no âvoid SymbolTable::displayScope(SymbolTable::Symbol*)â member function declared in class âSymbolTableâ
SymbolTable.cpp:167: error: no âvoid SymbolTable::addSymboll(std::string)â member function declared in class âSymbolTableâ
[...]$
```

As far as I can tell, it seemed to think my displayScope function was not declared in the class header file.  In order to investigate this further, I added a new function called addSymboll which was identical to the existing addSymbol function.  However, it's giving me the same error message for this new function.  In fact, after a couple of hours spent trying to compile this, it seems that I cannot add any new functions to this class at all.  I am at a complete loss as to what could be causing this.  **Any ideas would be appreciated!**

Comment: "g++ broken?" No. Blaming a bug on the compiler is the sign of not being a good enough programmer.

Comment: Mostly likely explanation is that you have two copies of your SymbolTable.h file. You are editing one copy but g++ is picking up the other copy. Or maybe you just aren't saving your changes. Try putting a deliberate error in SymbolTable.h and see if the compiler picks it up.

Comment: Okay so I know it's probably not g++, but this class IS compiling in Visual Studio.  (Not very helpful since the whole program must compile on Linux eventually)

Comment: Well if you are copying files between Windows and Linux I think that makes my explanation even more likely.

Comment: BTW you do not need include guards in a cpp file, only in a header file.

Comment: Good idea.  Just added a comment to the top of each file, transfered them to the server again, and looked at them in pico to make sure the comment got transfered (hence the right files), then compiled and ran into the same problems :(

Comment: Did not know that about the guards.  Good info.

Comment: OK now try putting in the deliberate error, that's the acid test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18703/discussion-between-alex-johnson-and-john)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had previously only been deleting the object (.o) files when cleaning.  What I ended up having to do here was delete the .gch files as well.  There was nothing wrong with the actual code or g++ (despite the old version running on the school servers).

Answer (score 3):

G++ also tells me:

> error: invalid preprocessing directive #defineSYMBOLTABLE_H

Add a space after `#define`:

> #defineSYMBOLTABLE_H

Comment: whoops!  copy+paste error on my part.

Comment: @AlexJohnson lol How is it possible to make such mistake if you do copy&paste? I think this answer solves the issue

Comment: When I originally copied and pasted, the spacing was strange in that position, as if there was a tab hidden there.  I believe I pressed backspace and immediately switched over to edit the original file (thinking this might be the problem).  After confirming that it wasn't, I came back to my post window, but forgot to replace the deleted tab with a space.

Comment: If I add a space, the source compiles fine on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.6.3)

Comment: If I add a space, the source does not compile on the school server (Red Hat 4.1.2-52, g++ 4.1.2).  I now believe this is a version issue.